# How to speed up cassandra "in" queries or 1,000s of single queries using pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I have thousands of queries that I need to issue.  Each query is along the lines of

```
select sample_time, value from table where company=123 and location=some-place and id=<id>
```

the only difference in the queries is the id.  I had been using cassandra driver in python and running concurrent queries where each query was for a specific id.  I believe this to be faster than a single query with multiple ids

```
.... and id in {1,000's of ids}
```

I am porting this to Spark and using a cluster to speed this up but I'm not sure how to write it efficiently.  I currently am using spark sql and running the following

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

...

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql = SQLContext(sc)

tbl = sql.read.format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra').load(table=table, keyspace=keyspace)

df  = tbl.select('sample_time', 'value') \
          .where(
              (col('company') == company) & \
              (col('location') == location) & \
              (col('id').isin(id_set)
            ).toPandas()
```

Is there a more efficient way to issue this query? Should I look to concurrency or parallelism on top of spark? Would it make more sense to issue 1,000s of single queries, join the resulting RDDs, then convert to pandas dataframe and finally run my aggregations?

Comment: What does your CASSANDRA `PRIMARY KEY` definition look like?

Comment: ((company, location, id), sample_time)